# Getting most recent record based on datetime column SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I am trying to select the most recent record. Right now it is returning all records. Which makes since, because I have not put in a filter to get most recent, I am unsure of how to do that. Here is my code:

```
select 
    c.my_Name, a.my_Num, d.myBrand, a.order_bill, a.myDate 
from
    [table1] a
left join 
    [table2] b on a.[myCode] = b.[myCode]
left join 
    [table3] c on c.myTag = b.myTag
left join 
    [table4] d on a.[myHash] = d.[myHash] 
where  
    c.[myName] = 'test name'
```

I am wanting to get most recent record from the table, I am guessing the most efficient way is to get most recent `a.myDate`.

Comment: 1. Use `order by a.myDate DESC` , 2. Leave the date formatting at client end.

Comment: where will the order go? At the end of the select?

Comment: @codeFinatic here is something that you should keep readily at your disposal this is what things such as google are for [SQL Basics Tutorial - Order-By](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-order-by-clause.htm) also please clarify if you want `Most recent RECORD or RECORDS` I think that will also filter down in regards to the number of ambiguous answers that you may be getting for example selecting `top` verses doing your Search Criteria and using a Where Clause with an `Order By`

Comment: Also note that when you apply a WHERE clause to a column in an outer joined table, that outer join effectively becomes an inner join.

Comment: You really should not ask two questions at once. As your first question had been answered, remove the second part and make it a single question (Or just search at SO, at this surely had been answered before)

Comment: Good point @OleAlbers. I Will do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd write

```
SELECT TOP 1 
c.my_Name, a.my_Num, d.myBrand, a.order_bill, CONVERT(char(10), a.myDate,126) 
FROM [table1] a
LEFT JOIN [table2] b on a.[myCode] = b.[myCode]
LEFT JOIN [table3] c on c.myTag=b.myTag
LEFT JOIN [table4] d on a.[myHash] = d.[myHash] 
WHERE  c.[myName] = 'test name'  
ORDER BY a.myDate DESC
```

Comment: This is 99% the right answer, but it doesn't address the date formatting issue in the last sentence.  Can you edit this to address that?

Comment: Screw it, I fixed it myself.  :)  +1 for the n00b.  Welcome aboard!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might help

```
select c.my_Name, a.my_Num, d.myBrand, a.order_bill, MAX(a.myDate) 
from [table1] a
left join [table2]  b on a.[myCode] = b.[myCode]
left join [table3] c on c.myTag=b.myTag
left join [table4] d on a.[myHash] = d.[myHash] 
where  c.[myName] = 'test name'
group by c.my_Name, a.my_Num, d.myBrand, a.order_bill
order by a.myDate DESC
```

This will grab distinct records with the greatest (most recent) a.myDate, grouped by your other elements.

Be aware of duplicates. Use your duplicate criteria keys in the select statement, or whatever elements you absolutely *need* to be distinct.